# С чего начать изучения программирования

Tags: windows

Какой язык программирования начать учить? Какой язык наиболее подходит для написания программ под ОС Windows?

Comment: начать с определения поля деятельности...а то ...поверь...на такие грабли и камни наткнешься, когда начнешь хвататься за каждую гадость....

Comment: начать изучать программирование стоит с математики в институте/школе и учебника по алгоритмам

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала я бы советовал освоить "Поиск"...

[Один](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/4575/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC)
[Два](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/18520/%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83)
[Три](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/9004/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-unix-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)
[Четыре](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/8902/%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C)
[Пять](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/7288/%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%83-%D1%8D%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)
[Шесть](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/6456/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0)
[Семь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/5713/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C)
[Восемь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/5425/%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83)
[Девять](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/5392/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)
[Десять](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/5261/%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

И это только на этом форуме по запросу "программист".

Answer (score 0):

Давным давно писал [статью у себя в блоге](http://coderlife.ru/progr/kakoj-yazyk-programmirovaniya-vybrat-dlya-izucheniya.html), возможно она косвенно поможет вам найти ответ на ваш вопрос.

Comment: У вас в комментарии к статье есть ссылка на другую статью "Traditional Programming Language Job Trends – August 2010", странно, почему они не брали во внимание PHP и Python...

Comment: сейчас перечитал статью "Traditional Programming Language Job Trends – August 2010" и честно не нашел ответа на ваш вопрос, вероятно автор данной статьи не относил PHP и Python к "Traditional Programming Languages", хм хотя perl там есть...

Comment: Да и я о чем. Хотя, конечно, популярность Java не может не радовать.